# Ruby on Rails: Search collection_check_boxes on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, search

In my RoR application I have functionality that allows a user to select contacts to send an email to. I want to add to this functionality so that a user can search the contacts.

Currently, the contacts are displayed on the `views/emails/form.html.erb` in checkboxes that the user can select through:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, :firstname %>
```

Is it possible to build on this by adding a search bar above the checkboxes that allows the user to search the checkboxes by first name?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a form to work with an unobstrusive javascript.

Like

```
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Form outside your main form... the REMOTE flag will tell rails 
       to prevent the default behaviour of a form make a request 
       for JS response --!>
  <%= form_tag contacts_path, remote: true, method: :get do  %>
    <%= input_tag :search %> 
    <%= button_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>

  <div id="email-form">
    <%= form_for @email, email_path do |f| %>
      <!-- Many inputs relative with email omited--!>

      <div class="contact-list">
      </div>

      <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Have an controller/action that search for your contacts and returns it for a js view...

```
// ContactController

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @contacts = Contact.all }
    format.js { @contacts = Contact.find_by(firstname: params[:search]) }
  end
end
```

And have a view for that action/controller that manipulate the html to append the contacts to be selected

```
// views/contacts/index.js.erb
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact-list').append("<%= collection_check_boxes :email, :contact_ids, @collection, :id, :firstname %>")
})
```

That is a very simple example... and I don't handle repetition... if you search for the same thing twice...